# user is nil in CanCan initializer with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin, cancan

Infos :

- Rails 4.0.2
- CanCan (1.6.10)
- Devise (3.2.4)
- ActiveAdmin (1.0.0.pre)

I'm trying to use cancan gem to manage authorizations access my backoffice (activeadmin).
I followed here: the tutorial http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html#using_the_cancan_adapter

The thing is the "user" variable is always nil in the cancan's initializer, even when there is a user logged in.

Here is my code:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    return unless user

    if user.has_operator_role? :active_admin
      can :manage, ActiveAdmin::Page, name: 'Dashboard'
  end
end
```

I put a debugger before the "return unless user" line and the "user" variable is always nil.
In the views, the "current_user" variable is correctly set BTW.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

I also tried with CanCanCan gem but it doesn't solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

CanCan is dead and barely supported in Rails 4.

You can try:

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

Comment: It seems that it didn't solve the problem!

"user" is still nil.

I think it's because the "current_user" is not set in ActiveAdmin controllers? How to set it?

Thanks!

Comment: Solved! I had to specify the current_user_method in active_admin config file : "config.current_user_method = :current_user". Simple...